# Change linear gradient background per element

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a list of elements that each have a linear gradient which gets animated after they load.  The CSS looks like this.

```
li {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 10%, white 10%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position:right bottom;
  -webkit-animation:colorChange;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorChange {
  from {background-position:right bottom;}
  to {background-position:left bottom;}
}
```

That works fine, but what I'd like to do is change the percentages per element.  I tried taking out the `background` property and setting it as a `style` attribute on the element, but the animation went away in that case (it just loaded with the color already partially filled).

I am a CSS super noob so I'm probably doing something stupid.  Help?

Comment: define different classes and apply those classes to your `li`s.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with CSS although it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Javascript might be able to do something or possible adjusting the `background:position` for each class..

Comment: You can use `nth-child(n)` selector for giving it patterned change. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/q6yghtw9/

Comment: The difference is meant to be based on specific data about the element, i.e. not just its order in the list. I don't really want to define a different class for each one because there are potentially a lot of different values.